# how to install Windows on a Dell from 2015 that only came with Linux

Tags: linux, windows, operating-systems

I want to install Windows on a Dell (from 2015, the Precision Tower 5810).
The machine came only with Linux installed on it.
Is this possible, and if so, how would I acquire Windows for this?

Comment: On the Dell site, there is an area that lets me download a file to re-install the OS, but I no longer want the original OS (i.e. Linux), I now need Windows.
https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/drivers/osiso/recoverytool/wt64a

Comment: You need to download the bootable ISO, and write it to a USB drive. It has been asked many many times https://superuser.com/search?q=install+windows+iso

Comment: You can install any OS you want you don't need a special OS from Dell. Just download or buy it and install it.